# Hibernate Criteria with EmbeddedId not generate correct sql query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have the following mapping of my classes:

```
@Entity
Class A{
    @EmbeddedId 
    B id;
    String notImportant;
}

@Entity
Class B {
    C c;
}

Class C {
String name;
}
```

---

When i use the follow criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.createAlias("id.c", "c");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", "Whatever"));
criteria.list();
```

---

```
Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select
        this_.notImportant as DOAT2_77_0_ 
    from
        A this_ 
    where
        c.name=?

2017-04-15 21:03:02,211 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - ORA-00904: "c"."name": identificador inválido
```

So i understand that the "c" identified would be defined by a Inner join...
As the criteria use this identifier without declaration...

Answer (score 0):

- The class `B` must be annotated with `@Embeddable`;
- Also check if the class `B` has the `getC` and `setC` methods;

If the error persist, please post your full code. :-)